# How do i check if it should be an or a in python?

Tags: python

so im making a generator (doesn't really matter what one it is)
and im trying to make the a/ans appear before nouns correctly.

for example:
"an apple plays rock paper scissors with a banana"
and not:
"a apple plays rock paper scissors with an banana"

the default thing for the not-yet determined a/an is `"<a>"`
so i need to replace the `"<a>"` with either a or an depending on if the letter after it is a vowel or not.

how would i do this?

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: There's no lexical rule you can apply. "A hat" but "an hour", "a ukulele" but "an umbrella". It's the pronunciation that's important, not the spelling.

Comment: why not use a language generator that understands English grammar, e.g. GPT2?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd think that you're going to be looking for something like:

```py
def handle_sentence(sentence):
    sentence_fixed = ""
    idx = 0
    while idx < len(sentence):  # iterate over each character in the sentence
        char = sentence[idx]
        if (
            char == "<" and idx < len(sentence) - 3 and sentence[idx : idx + 3] == "<a>"
        ):  # we've found a not-yet determined a/an
            if (
                idx + 4 < len(sentence) - 1
            ):  # we need to ensure that we aren't at the end of the sentence string
                if sentence[idx + 4] in ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u"):
                    sentence_fixed += "an"
                else:
                    sentence_fixed += "a"
                idx += 3
                continue
        sentence_fixed += char
        idx += 1
    return sentence_fixed
```

Example function call:

`handle_sentence("<a> apple plays rock paper scissors with <a> banana")`

Example output:

`an apple plays rock paper scissors with a banana`

Comment: For sure, but the user seemed to be looking for an example based on the naive replacement of (if vowel then "an" else "a")

Comment: thanks :) that works well

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code

Input:

```
a apple an day keeps doctor away
```

Code:

```
def convert(lst):  
    return str(lst).translate(None, '[],\'') 

string = "a apple an day keeps doctor away"
a_list = string.split(" ")
for i in range(len(a_list)):
    try:
        if a_list[i] == 'a':
            if a_list[i+1][0] in ['a','e','i','o','u']:
                a_list[i] = 'an'
        elif a_list[i] == 'an':
            if a_list[i+1][0] not in ['a','e','i','o','u']:
                a_list[i] = 'a'
    except e:
        print(str(e))

print(convert(a_list))
```

Output:

```
an apple a day keeps doctor away
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy to understand code is:

```
s = "a apple plays rock paper scissors with an banana"
wl = s.split(" ")  # word list

vowels = ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U")
    
for i,word in enumerate(wl):
    if word == "a" or word == "an":
        if wl[i+1].startswith(vowels):
            wl[i] = "an"
        else:
            wl[i] = "a"
wl = " ".join(wl)
print(wl)
```

output:

```
'an apple plays rock paper scissors with a banana'
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code

1. first find letter 'a' or 'an' in string and keep track of it
2. then find first word after it
3. if word starts with vowel: make it 'an'
4. Else: make it 'a'
5. this rules breaks with words like 'hour' or 'university' so also make exception rule(find a list of words if u can)